# docker-compose up --exit-code-from exits without error when system under test crashes fast

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I am creating some integration tests for my docker images using `docker-compose`. `docker-compose` has a neat flag `--exit-code-from` to allow stopping all dockers and returning exit code from the test docker once the tests are finished.

Trouble is however that `--exit-code-from` includes automatically the flag `--abort-on-container-exit`. This is quite logical, but creates the following problem:

**Normal case**

1. system under test starts
2. integration-tests run tests and exit with error code X
3. all containers are stopped
4. exit code X is returned.

**Problem case**

1. system under test starts
2. before integration-tests has the time to finish, system under test exits with an error
3. all containers are stopped
4. exit code 0 is returned! So it is as if the tests succeeded.

You can reproduce this with the following files:

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM alpine as development
ENTRYPOINT [ "/bin/false" ]

FROM alpine as test
ENTRYPOINT [ "/bin/sleep", "3" ]
```

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: "3.5"
services:
  sut:
    build:
      context: .
      target: development
  test:
    build:
      context: .
      target: test
```

and then running

```
docker-compose up --build --exit-code-from test
echo $? # print exit code from previous command
```

which will return exit code 0.

**I would like exit code 0 to mean: integration tests really ran and were successful.**

**EDIT:**
after seeing this issue https://github.com/docker/compose/pull/6077/commits merged into `docker-compose` 1.22.0; I ran again with the latest version of `docker-compose` (1.24.1 as of now), but I run into my problem still.

Comment: I got `docker-test_sut_1 exited with code 1` I have `docker-compose version 1.23.2,` `docker-py version: 3.6.0` and docker `Version:          18.09.2`

Comment: yes indeed, but the exit code is 0. Run `echo $?` just after that command, that will print the exit code.

Comment: yes sure, docker run to the end without error, the test in docker is not

Comment: test_sut_1 = system under test docker, not the test docker.
The system under test exited with error before the tests could finish. So docker-compose concludes with exit code 0... which is now what I expect if I run tests... I want to know if my docker is good to go, which is obviously not the case!

Answer (score 1):

This is the only workaround I have found so far. Not the cleanest solution, but it does the trick:

```
docker-compose up --build --exit-code-from test | grep -q "_test_1 exited with code 0" $TMP
```

a longer version in a clean bash script with option parsing, showing the output of docker-compose: https://gist.github.com/chrismaes87/7297d34d356b07a00a5da5f8e425326c